# How to check last block in which storage variable was modified?

Tags: blockchain, storage, state-trie, explorers, leveldb

I am looking for method to quick chceck in which block variable was modified last.
Assuming I have geth database synced in archive mode, that means I have all previous world states tries and accounts storages tries.
How can I check this fast. Is there a way to do this not checking previous worldstates states and storage tries?
Can I determine this block number looking only on bloom filters or whatever, more efficient than checking tries?

Comment: Does your contract emit an Event on storage modification? If so, then you can use bloom filters

Comment: Good to know thanks for answer, and is there a way to check this if contract does not emit events?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do it. You would probably have to go block by block and search for transactions, since the bloom filters only filter for logged events, not transaction addresses.